# Ubuntu on WSL2 の Emacs が Segmentation Fault で起動できない

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, wsl, wsl-2

昨日まで動作していたEmacsが、Ubuntuをupgrade後、Segmentation Faultで動作しなくなりました。

動作環境

- Windows 10
- WSL2
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Emacs 28.1 (build 1.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-05-31

`emacs -Q`も同じように動作しません。
`emacs -nw` は動作します。
`xeyes`は動作するので、X Windowも動作していると思います。

何か分かりましたらよろしくお願い致します。

以下にsegment faultのログを挙げます。

```
$ emacs& [1] 566 ~ $ Backtrace: emacs[0x530a92] emacs[0x4269f7]
emacs[0x426ee1] emacs[0x52efed] emacs[0x52f06d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f2118225520]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x1471253)[0x7f21014c9253]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x1470e54)[0x7f21014c8e54]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x14c11c5)[0x7f21015191c5]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa8719)[0x7f2102b00719]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa5bd5)[0x7f2102afdbd5]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa653a)[0x7f2102afe53a]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2c445d4)[0x7f2102c9c5d4]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x2dbab3)[0x7f2110df3ab3]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x2fee0c)[0x7f2110e16e0c]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x24c73f)[0x7f2110d6473f]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0xc47c9)[0x7f21111617c9]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x492ca)[0x7f21110e62ca]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4919c)[0x7f21110e619c]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4910f)[0x7f21110e610f]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x482a9)[0x7f21110e52a9]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x242fb2)[0x7f2110d5afb2]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x244533)[0x7f2110d5c533]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x244d3b)[0x7f2110d5cd3b]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4851c)[0x7f21110e551c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4cb56)[0x7f2111d7cb56]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4b10c)[0x7f2111d7b10c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4b3ba)[0x7f2111d7b3ba]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xacdf0)[0x7f21112dcdf0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x6edf6b)[0x7f211191df6b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x6edea7)[0x7f211191dea7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xad703)[0x7f21112dd703]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb6749)[0x7f21112e6749]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x30243)[0x7f2113193243]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x36380)[0x7f2113199380]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x32eb5)[0x7f2113195eb5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0(epoxy_glx_version+0x2f)[0x7f2117f3945f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x74840)[0x7f211c1b0840]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x7beb9)[0x7f211c1b7eb9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x69aab)[0x7f211c1a5aab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_display_manager_open_display+0x14f)[0x7f211c17468f]
... ^C [1]+  Segmentation fault      emacs ~
```

Comment: 関係は無いかもしれませんが、こんなのを試してみては？ [Ubuntu22.04（WSL2）でGUIアプリが即Segmentation Faultする](https://zenn.dev/a106lab/articles/7ac5f3a3e94d17) 環境変数を追加してみるだけなので直ぐに試せるし元に戻せますから。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
その環境変数を使う（nVIDIAのグラボを無効化する）のもうまくいきましたが、同じ記事中の「WSLを最新にする」で完全に治りました！！

Answer (score 0):

WSLを最新に更新することで問題の現象は解決しました。

更新するには、cmd.exeから以下のコマンドを実行します。

```
wsl --update
```

参考記事：
[Ubuntu22.04（WSL2）でGUIアプリが即Segmentation Faultする](https://zenn.dev/a106lab/articles/7ac5f3a3e94d17)
[Windows Subsystem for Linux のトラブルシューティング](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/troubleshooting)